# How to calculate number of occurrences

Tags: visual-studio

Can someone show me how to make a number occurrences application in Visual Basic 2008? The program is supposed to prompt the user for a number and then it counts the occurrences of each number (0-9) in the user number. 
For example, a number of 122378 would print out: 
0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=1, 9=0,
It says to treat the number like a string, and the answer should be displayed in a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do it but so you understand - do this:

```vb
'prepare placeholder
dim dict as New Dictionary(of String, Integer) 
dict.Add("0", 0)
dict.Add("1", 0)
dict.Add("2", 0)
dict.Add("3", 0)
dict.Add("4", 0)
dict.Add("5", 0)
dict.Add("6", 0)
dict.Add("7", 0)
dict.Add("8", 0)
dict.Add("9", 0)

' Assuming you ask user to type into text box txtSubmittedNumber
' Parse your numbers and collect counts
For Each c as Char in txtSubmittedNumber.Text.ToCharArray()

    Dim key as String = c.ToString()
    dict(key) = dict(key) + 1

Next

' Assuming you fill results into listbox lstNumbers, just add your strings to display
For each kvp as KeyValuePair(of String, Integer) in dict

    lstNumbers.Items.Add(kvp.Key & "=" & kvp.Value.ToString())

Next
```

This is program for beginners. There is `Linq` of course but it is not going to be as clear what is going on because it substitutes loops, group by, etc.